# Ignore file(s) with Roxygen

Tags: r, backup, roxygen

I'm quite new in (and unwilling to learn) package creation/administration, so *excuse-moi* if I'm asking something trivial. I'm familiar with `git`, though, and I'd like to know if there's a similar functionality  to `.gitignore` in `roxygen`. Since I use `ESS`, I often have a lot of backup files (`*~`), which are then picked up and processed with `R CMD roxygen`. Of course, I'd like to skip that in a more elegant manner - right now I have a shell script with `find anolyzer/ -name "*~" -exec rm {} \;` that flushes the nasty backups... but I kind-of need them, and just want to ignore them on install.

**Disclaimer:**
*unwiling to learn* = *unwilling to comb down the lengthy manuals and desperate for neat, quick and dirty one-liner*

credits to [John Myles White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/426443/john-myles-white) for stressing the "unwilling" part

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way to ignore files with Roxygen/2 specifically, but there are a number of options available to avoid the problem.

- Delete the backups as you are now doing
- Instead of deleting them, move them to another directory outside of the package directory.
- Setup emacs to not save backups in your working directory (http://amitp.blogspot.com/2007/03/emacs-move-autosave-and-backup-files.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for something more... neat. Out-of-the-box-like =)

Comment: I think you want this: https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues/55.  Patches welcome ;)